# Tumblr API Get Original Poster's Username

Tags: php, json, api, tumblr

I'm working on a project that needs to get information from a Tumblr post. Specifically I'm looking for the posters username, caption, title of the blog, date/time and the URL. I have everything covered except the original posters username, for example I need `mclentil` from the post: `http://harperhug.tumblr.com/post/138269357957/mclentil-this-just-happened`

I've tried using the following:

```
https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/harperhug.tumblr.com/posts/photo?id=138269357957&api_key=***
```

Which gets me everything except for the username, `mclentil`, the only place that mentions it completely is in the direct HTML of the caption:

```
<p><a class=\"tumblr_blog\" href=\"http://mclentil.tumblr.com/post/76303232069\">mclentil</a>:</p>\n<blockquote>\n<p>This just happened..</p>\n</blockquote>
```

I need a way to get that username, for not only this post but other similar posts on Tumblr.

Comment: Imgur? ......

Comment: @Viney Oops, mistype

Comment: Can use `api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info` api if you know poster's user id.But `https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/harperhug.tumblr.com/posts?id=138269357957` doesn't return the poster's user id, i have never tried retrieving poster's id before so not aware of any potential api

Comment: @Viney Any ideas? I need to get it somehow

Comment: Well only `posts/link` API provides author name but problem is it returns a collection of posts and no way to filter a post by id so you have to manually loop over and check if the current post id matches the one you are intrested in

Comment: you need to add reblog_info to the url like this
https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/harperhug.tumblr.com/posts/photo?id=138269357957&reblog_info=true&api_key=

and then get it from reblogged_root_name